# Why didn't I receive this two-factor authentication code?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, two-factor-authentication

I logged into a MacBook to complete an app purchase and was asked to enter a 2FA (Two-Factor Authentication) code, with the dialog stating that I needed to verify from a trusted device (presumably the iPhone on the account). However, no 2FA code never popped up, and I had to get a text after several retries.

What went wrong, or am I doing something incorrectly? iPhone is Version 11.2.6, Mac is OS X 10.11.6.

Two-Factor Authentication is enabled.

[image: enabled]

Comment: Did you setup your account with 2FA or is your question about not having that setup but you were asked anyway?  The way it's written is a bit confusing as to what you're issue you're asking for help.

Comment: Apologies. The account is set up with 2FA.

Comment: NP.  The 2FA code is sent to every trusted device that's signed-in with that Apple ID.  Could someone else have seen the code on a different device and clicked it away?

Comment: No, there is only one trusted device at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't receive the 2Fa code, in terms of the pop-up window pops up:

You can **manually retrieve/generate a 2FA code on an associated device.**

On iOS 15.6 do the following:

**Settings->iCloud Account->Password&Security->Get Verification Code (at the very bottom)**